# Windows 8.1 jump list visual bug

Tags: windows-8.1, jumplist

I just finished a fresh install of windows 8.1 on my new SSD. Whenever I open the "Jump List" for items on the task bar, I see this...

[image]

I haven't changed any theme settings. This is what happens immediately after a fresh install. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to uninstall KB3072318.

https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3f4yz9/my_jump_list_icons_are_huge_and_weird/

Comment: How do I uninstall an update?

Comment: Figured it out, and it worked! Thank you so much!